# I can not create a new web API using Entity Framework in .NET Core 3.1.9

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-5.0

Hi im having problem to create a Web API Controller using EF, currently im using .Net Core 3.1.9 and im not ready to upgrade at .Net Core 5.0 but in the same time i cant generate a API Controller.

[image]

The Updates that appeared are like below
[image]
before that when this problem appeared i just updated the packages and it worked perfectly but now i cant update i want to keep it in v3.1.9 for the moment.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you meeting this issue when you try to create API controller based on the dbContext? If that is the case, try to create an API controller without DbContext, whether it works well or not? Besides, try to clear/ rebuild the project, and reopen the Visual Studio check if the issue disappears.

Comment: Yes i have the issue just when i want to create API Controller based on dbContext otherwise i can create a empty one without a problem. i Tried to clear and Rebuild the project same problem, i think its all about packages updates, i updated visual studio and i think that's why VS request to upgrade the packages too.. i guess!

Comment: you could also try to clear the NuGet Cache: VS Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager ->Package Manager Setting-> General -> Clear All Nuget Cache(s).

Comment: No it doesnt work either but im going to use Empty API Controller and i'll inject dependencies manually, anyway thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working. I was getting the same error and here is how I fixed the issue.

1. Goto obj folder and look for file "ProjectName.csproj.nuget.g.props" in my case it is: "PaymentDetailsWebAPI.csproj.nuget.g.props"
2. Search for Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design
   you will get something like this:

   ```
   Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design\3.1.23\build\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.props"
   ```
3. Now look for Nuget package version. In my case I got "3.1.23".
4. Now update following packages to: whatever version you have in your file.

   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools